# Get the dynamic height of a clone object

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, I would like to get the height of a clone object BEFORE it is appended to the body.

Note: I didn't specify the width and height in CSS (this is the requirement).

Is it possible?

```
<body>

<style>.square {}</style>

<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var o = $(".square").clone(true);
    $(o).css('height','auto').html("Some stuff...<br/><br/>");

    // output 0 (Question: how to get the height?)
    console.log($(o).height());

    $(o).appendTo("body");

    // output the height (i.e. 38)
    console.log($(o).height());
});
</script>
<div class="square"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try it? And what does the size of an empty `div` with no explicit dimensions _mean_?

Comment: How can you get the height of something that isn't placed in the DOM? It doesn't have a height yet!

Comment: @Jack: That's not strictly true.

Comment: It means I can insert the dynamic content (i.e. "Some stuff..." in the codes above) AND THEN get the height of the DIV BEFORE it is appended to the body. Please help.

Comment: @Tomalak apologies, but regardless of if it has a height or not before being put into the DOM, I'm pretty sure there is no way to measure the element's height.

Comment: @Jack: thanks Jack. I hope this is not true...

Comment: @Jack: You should [try these things](http://jsfiddle.net/RMxHW/) before making false assertions.

Comment: @Ronald T - I think it is, but I also think that Frederic Hamidi's answer below should help you out.

Comment: @Tomalak: thanks for the link, I will also try it.

Comment: @Jack: What you [can't do](http://jsfiddle.net/WheFf/) is get the height if that's based on contents. In fairness, with the height set to `'auto'`, I suppose that might be what the OP's after. Still, it's that the text doesn't affect the container's height until insertion into the DOM; that's not quite the same as "it doesn't have a height yet", or "there is no way to measure the element's height".

Comment: @Tomalak it alerts '0' for me: http://cl.ly/051y3E0P1P3Z3o3u2T0N

Comment: @Tomalak very interesting, I'm on the latest Chrome here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you cannot reliably measure elements before adding them to the document, one way is to take advantage of absolute positioning to put the element outside of the viewport:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $o = $(".square").clone(true);
    $o.css("height", "auto").html("Some stuff...<br/><br/>");

    $o.css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: "-10000px"
    }).appendTo("body");

    console.log($o.height());      // Works.

    $o.css("position", "static");  // Reset positioning.
});
```

Comment: @Ronald T if this solution work you should mark it as accepted "click the tick besides the answer" :)

Comment: @Jack: thanks Jack! Obviously, I am a new user, and this is my first post in stackoverflow. :D